# unable to run SDK Manager.exe

Tags: android

unable to run SDK Manager.exe  it will give error like this..

GetTempFileName failed
The directory name is invalid.

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try unzipping the package in a folder that isn't your root directory, and make sure that you are running with full permissions.

Comment: what version of windows? what directory did you unzip to?